# When using formula interface of caret::train() can I manipulate the dot in use target ~

Tags: r, r-caret

```
# Fit random forest

model.rf <- caret::train(
  category ~.,
  tuneLength = 10,
  data = train, method = "ranger",
  trControl = train_control 
)
```

I also want to try running the model minus a variable called "cad" within my train data.

```
# Fit random forest excluding cad feature
model.rf <- caret::train(
  category ~ dplyr::select(train, -cad),
  tuneLength = 10,
  data = train, method = "ranger",
  trControl = train_control 
)
```

> ```
> Error in model.frame.default(form = category ~ dplyr::select(train, c(-category,  : 
>   invalid type (list) for variable 'dplyr::select(train, c(-category, -cad))'
> ```

Want to know, can I do something like this:

```
category ~ .[,-"cad"],
```

Comment: category ~ . - cad

Comment: You could probably also do the `select` in your data argument, like `data = dplyr::select(train, -cad)`.

Comment: Ah! Of course, I need to step back. I should probably delete this?

Comment: Presumably there's no advantage to using one over the other? Just preference? Mind if I leave this question open since I did some googling but couldn't find an exact answer on initial search. If you want to turn the comments into an answer I'l accept either

Comment: @Roland would something like this also work then ```category ~. -c(cad, blah)```

Comment: category ~ . - cad * blah You should probably study help("formula").

Comment: Doing this with a formula has advantages if you want to compare nested models or update a model.